# webaddress in moodle launch URL instead ipaddress or localhost

Tags: php, mysql, dns, moodle

I am using Moodle 2.5.4 (Build: 20140113), php 5.4.7, MySQL 5.5.27, Apache 2.4.3, XAMPP server version 1.8.1. I am able to launch the Moodle using the 'ipaddress' or 'localhost'.

I would like to change the Web address instead ipaddress or localhost. How can I do that? What are the files needs to be changed.

I have tried by modifying config.php file $CFG->wwwroot but no luck. Please let me know the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

**start** -> **run** -> `%WINDIR%\System32\Drivers\etc` and edit file **hosts**
for example

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   test1.ru
your_ip_address  testmoodle.in
```

now go to http://test1.ru and you will see your localhost on this domain

Comment: Hi, I have tried the above scenario but no luck. It throws the error. Unknown Host

Description: Unable to locate the server named "testlms.in" --- the server does not have a DNS entry. Perhaps there is a misspelling in the server name, or the server no longer exists. Double-check the name and try again. Please help me out.

Comment: try add your ip address like `your_ip_connaction_here   test1.ru` in hosts file

Comment: Can you please make it more clear? I have changed hosts file from 'localhost' to 'testmoodle.in'. When I try to launch the page using 'http://testmoodle.in' it throws the above error. What needs to done to resolve this issue?

Comment: try `your_ip_address  testmoodle.in`  not 127.0.0.1 . you can go to http://ipaddress.com and see whats you ip

Comment: NO. I am getting the same error. I  would like to launch the moodle page using 'http://testmoodle.in' Do I need to modify any other file(s)?